# tapestry 5 session bean

Tags: java, tapestry

The problem should be common, but i can't find any clear information about it.

Basically, each client of my web app is building an object, i would like to store this object in a session bean in order to be reused in different web pages.

I m actualy using a single static class for developpement ease, but now i need it to be available with multi clients (the static class, of course, gives the same static object for all clients).

Can tapestry handle session beans ? if not, what is the best work around to use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`@SessionState`](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/SessionState.html) annotation to attach values to the session and use them in multiple pages:

```
@SessionState
private MyType myVar;
```

Also take a look at the [session storage section in the Tapestry docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/session-storage.html).

Comment: there's also the @Persist annotation

Comment: @Pstanton: Sure, but that won't work across pages, which is what the OP is asking for.